# role position on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have problem with position and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
async def cipcia(ctx, *, arg):
    message = ctx.message
    guild = ctx.guild
    mama = 10
    await guild.create_role(name=arg, position=mama)
```

error:

```
 Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: 'position' is not a valid field.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[create_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_role#discord.Guild.create_role) does not have a `position` parameter.  You will need to use [edit_role_positions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit_role_positions#discord.Guild.edit_role_positions) to change the positions of your roles.

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
async def role_edit(ctx, *, name: str=''):
   message = ctx.message
   guild = ctx.guild
   mama = 10

   role = await guild.create_role(name=name)
   await role.edit(position=mama)
```